# Javascript counting duplicate entries in a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve this puzzle, below is the instruction

> You are given an array strarr of strings and an integer k. Your task is to return the first longest string consisting of k consecutive strings taken in the array.
>
> Example:
>
> longest_consec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", >"abigail"], 2) --> "abigailtheta"
> n being the length of the string array, if (n = 0) or (k > n) or (k <= 0) return "";

Below is my code that I have worked on so far. I have explanations commented on them.

```
function longestConsec(strarr, k) {

 if((strarr.length == 0) || (k > strarr.length) || (k <= 0)){
    return ""; // solves return of empty string
    }

    var empty = '';
    var str = strarr.split(' '); // then splits into an array which can be cycled through.

for (var i = 0; i < strarr.length; i++){ // cycle through length;
    for(var j = 0; j < strarr[i]; j++){  // cycle through ontop of that
    if (strarr[i] === strarr[j]){  // compare if any of cycle 1 = cycle 2
      empty.concat(strarr[i]);    // if it does, concat the word into a string
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ??? Read your Q several times and example answer and its answer makes not sense. ? Does the order of the strings not matter??? If so does that mean the same for the content of each string?

Comment: The string `.concat()` method returns a *new* string, it doesn't modify your existing `empty` string.

Comment: The original question is terrible. I can read every word, but cannot understand the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

```
function longest_consec(strarr, k) {
  var longest = '';
  for (var i = 0, testString; i <= strarr.length - k; i++) {
    testString = strarr.slice(i, i + k).join('');
    if (testString.length > longest.length) longest = testString;
  }
  return longest;
}
console.log(longest_consec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"], 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I had a bug. Didn't try all the test cases.

The sneaky part is here:

```
sub = arr.slice(ix, ix + k).join('');
```

You take the array that they give you and copy a chunk with the `slice` method. This takes a start and an end value. So you start with the index, and add `k` to it. Then you use the `join` method to slam the chunk together as a string.

Now it's simple to compare the length of this string to the longest one you've found so far. We start with an empty string so the first chunk will always be bigger.

If you don't know about `slice` and `join`, it becomes a bit harder.

```js
console.log(longest_consec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"], 2));
console.log(longest_consec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"], 3));
console.log(longest_consec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"], 0));
console.log(longest_consec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"], -1));
console.log(longest_consec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"], 9));

function longest_consec(arr, k) {
    var longest = "";
    var sub = "";

    if(k < 0 || k > arr.length) return "";

    for(var ix = 0; ix < arr.length; ix++) {
        sub = arr.slice(ix, ix + k).join('');
        if(sub.length > longest.length) longest = sub;
    }

    return longest;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added a small piece and it worked. If you could help me understand this, I would be grateful.

Comment: `function longestConsec(arr, k) {
  var longest = "";
  var sub = "";
  if((arr.length == 0) || (k > arr.length) || (k <= 0)){
    return '';
  }

  for (var ix = 0; ix < arr.length; ix++) {
    sub = arr.slice(ix, ix + k).join('');
    if (sub.length > longest.length) longest = sub;
  }

  return longest;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
const Array = ["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"];
let bigArray = Array[0];
if(Array.length > 0){
  Array.forEach(value => {
    if(value.length > bigArray.length){
        bigArray = value;
    }   
  });
  console.log(bigArray); //abigail
  //bigArray now contain the biggest string in the "Array" variable
}else{
    //array is empty
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a version using the [array `.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) together with [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Slice) and [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). This is basically the same as the other `.slice().join()` answers, but using `.reduce()` instead of an explict `for` loop:

```js
function longest_consec(arr, k) {
  if (k > arr.length || k < 1) return '';
  return arr.reduce(function(prevLongest, c, i, a) {
    var str = a.slice(i, i + k).join('');
    return str.length > prevLongest.length ? str : prevLongest;
  }, '');
}

console.log(longest_consec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"], 2));
console.log(longest_consec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"], 9));
console.log(longest_consec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"], 0));
```

Or my code-golf rewrite of the above using arrow functions:

```js
var longest_consec = (a, k) =>
  k>a.length||k<1?'':a.reduce((p,c,i,a)=>(c=a.slice(i,i+k).join('')).length>p.length?c:p,'');

console.log(longest_consec(["zone","abigail","theta","form","libe","zas","theta","abigail"],2));
console.log(longest_consec(["zone","abigail","theta","form","libe","zas", "theta","abigail"],9));
console.log(longest_consec(["zone","abigail","theta","form","libe", "zas","theta","abigail"],0));
```